# What plant could I grow to and safely consume to stimulate muscle growth?

Tags: herbs

Plants are often used for precursors to many pharmicuticals (i.e. Big Tooth Aspin bark to treat rheumatism and fevers), and want to grow my muscles, so I was wondering if you were adding 1 plant to your garden that you consume on occasion to promote muscle size growth, what plant would that be, and why?

I understand that this is a hybrid question, but some gardeners often grow plants that they only consume themselves on occasion, because to grow, process, and sell to others would be illegal, but posession of is completely **legal**.

Comment: All legumes and grains, bananas, avocados, broccoli, and spinach, among others, have protein. Other than eating protein, it is exercise and not supplements that grow muscles.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about nutrition; please see the [help/on-topic] for more information about the type of questions we welcome here.